# I receive a status 401 error: Unauthorized when i attempt to call my Secured API by keycloak

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I expose to you my problem.
I have a webapp that call a REST API to find the cart of the client.
The application and the API are secured with spring security and a SSO Keycloak.

Actually, my webapp is functional, if my don't protect my api, all are ready.

But when i want to secure my api with role, i have every time an error 401 error: unauthorized. In fact is good, my api is secured, but the client that have role "USER" can't access to his cart.

When i attempt to take my bearer token to keycloak, is a good token (past in jwt.io). I attempted to use curl, but the result is same.

I use Feign in my webapp to call the API.

My Keycloak configuration in my api

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "keycloak.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
public static class KeycloakConfigurationAdapter extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver(){
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy())
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

                .and()
                    .addFilterBefore(keycloakPreAuthActionsFilter(), LogoutFilter.class)
                    .addFilterBefore(keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter(), X509AuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())

                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/paniers/**").hasAuthority("USER")
                    .antMatchers("/commandes/**").hasRole("USER")
                    .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

My .properties for API

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://myserver:port/auth
keycloak.realm=wild_adventures
keycloak.resource=ms-commande
keycloak.credentials.secret=#######-####-####-####-###########
keycloak.bearer-only=true
```

My method in the controller of the api

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Récupère le panier avec la liste des évenements réservés ou renvoie un 404 NotFound")
@GetMapping(value = "paniers/{clientUuid}")
public Panier recupererPanier(@PathVariable(value = "clientUuid") String clientUuid) {

    Panier panier = this.panierManager.getPanierByClientUuid(clientUuid);

    if(panier == null)
        throw new PanierInexistantException("Le panier n'a pas été trouvé");

    return panier;
}
```

Thx for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok after some research, i have find to reason of my problem.

First, Zuul secure the Authorization header of my request...
To solve that, i added this line in my properties "zuul.sensitiveHeaders: Cookie, Set-Cookie" (So, Zuul just secure Cookie and Set-Cookie).

Next, in my code i send the good token, but i needed to precise "Bearer " before my token string.

Maybe that solution can help someone :)

Comment: You should be able to accept your own answer. This will mark this question as being answered.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed, that you mixed `hasAuthority` and `hasRole` methods in your security config. Should be either `hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")` or `hasRole("USER")`. Have you checked if `"/commandes/**"` resource works for you?

Comment: Oh sorry the hasAutority is just a test but in primary was hasRole. I had test the «/commandes/**» with curl and i had the same error.